# Jenkins job for remote deployment - multiple environments

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to create a generic Jenkins job for deploying different projects from different GIT repos and  branches to different application servers (in any combination).

I have 2 string build parameters for the repo and for the branch, and a small shell script in a pre-build step which based on the build params creates a `deploy.properties` file with properties `URL` and `PROFILE`.

Another pre-build step is the Inject environment variables which uses the `deploy.properties` file previously created.

I'm to use the URL property in the Jenkins Deploy Plugin in the following way: Tomcat URL field - `$URL`.

Also, in the build section, I'm using the PROFILE property: `clean install -P$PROFILE` .

The problem is that the placeholders or not replaced by the values I've set in the shell script. Not that is I do another post-build action and I'm echoing the same placeholders, the values are replaced and it seems to work. Other check I've done is the Environment Variables section from a given Build and the variable values are there, so the injection works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using curly brackets -P${PROFILE}

Answer (score 0):

Try the below and make sure you don't have the cmd in single quotes or anything.

```
clean install -P${PROFILE}
```